# ORA-06413: Connection not open. from ASP.NET and Oracle 10g

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, oracle10g, windows-7-x64

I am trying to connect oracle 10g 32 bit from a c# asp.net web application using oledbconnection and getting the following error :

```
ORA-06413: Connection not open.
```

It's connecting properly from windows application and TOAD/SQL* PLUS.

I googled the problem and tried all the possible solution (checking special character) but none of them helped.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it atlast. I uninstalled VS2010 from my machine. Format it. Again i install VS2010 in a new folder in c: called VS2010. Now its going fine. Thanks anyway all of you for your response.

Comment: the problem was because "(x84)" in the VS path. This is sad, but true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your .exe filename has more than one ".", or if your file path has parenthesis "()":

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10129961

Comment: what .exe filename you are talking about? can you specify?

Comment: OK - your .dll or your .asmx or whatever you have.  Look at the link, check your web application's file path.

Comment: my webapplication file path is following : C:\Users\arnabmvst\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3;

Comment: I am creating a new web application and trying to connect oracle through it. Please suggest something, this is very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a connection object. You have to open the connection to execute the SQL commands.

Lets say you created a connection object of oracle with name oracleConnection.

Then after that you have to use

```
oracleConnection.Open();
```

to open the connection to the oracle database you are trying to connect.
The other problem may be with your oracle service which might not be running. so check that the oracle service is running in the background.